# Django Query including a table where no relation can be followed

Tags: python, django, join, models, django-queryset

i'm trying to 'join' this 4 models in a query. My starting point is a Team.id. 
I am trying to get the SkillRecord into the result but i am completly lost.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User)
    id          = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, unique=True)
    ...

class Player(models.Model):
    id              = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...

class Transfer(models.Model):
    player          = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    seller          = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='transfer_seller')
    buyer           = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='transfer_buyer')
    date            = models.DateTimeField()
    ...

class SkillRecord(models.Model):
    player          = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    date            = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    ...
```

## Here is my humble approach so far

```
    def list_players(request, teamid):
        team = get_object_or_404(Team, id=teamid)
        players_transfers = Transfer.objects.filter(buyer=team).select_related('player')
```

I'm not really sure what would be my next step to get the SkillRecord model into the game.
I seem to lack the basic gist of those kind of problems so i will need a poke i guess.

Also, feel free to give me further ideas how to do this, i'm more or less sure i could also solve this whole Transfer thing using manytomanyfields or so.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab SkillRecord as well you need to add related_name:

```
class SkillRecord(models.Model):
    player          = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='skills')
    date            = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

then make the query:

```
qt = Transfer.objects.filter(...).select_related('player').prefetch_related('player__skills')
```

then retrieve them like so:

```
qt[0].player.skills.all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really gave me the insight and example i needed to understand the concept. Unfortunately i can't upvote yet, so have an imaginary upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions each Player has a Team so we can add.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

Then if you want the skillrecord start by there

```
SkillRecord.objects.filter(player__team=team)
```

Comment: This is exactly my problem, i don't really want to store the players current team inside the player. I wanted to use the date field to find any players team at that given time using the information stored in Transfer. I must have deleted it, Transfer has a datetime field.